# Trying to understand the polynomial quotient rings with an example

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am studying polynomial quotient rings and I've noticed that if I have say $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$, then by definition $$\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle = \{p(x) + \langle x^2+1\rangle \mid p(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \}.$$

and $p(x) + \langle x^2+1\rangle = \{p(x) + q(x)(x^2+1) \mid q(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \}$.

The terms $p(x) + q(x)(x^2+1)$ look very much like the division form for polynomials i.e $$f(x) =g(x)d(x) + r(x)$$ so in my case $p(x)$ would correspond to the remainder $r(x)$?

And it indeed seems to be that if I pick say $p(x) = 2x^3+3x^2+5x+6$, then preforming long division I have that $$\require{enclose}\begin{array}{rlc}\phantom{\color{Magenta}{x^{2}}+1}&\phantom{\enclose{longdiv}{}-}\begin{array}{rrrr}2 x&\color{GoldenRod}{+3}&\phantom{+5 x}&\phantom{+6}\end{array}&\\\color{Magenta}{x^{2}}+1&\phantom{-}\enclose{longdiv}{\begin{array}{cccc}2 x^{3}&+3 x^{2}&+5 x&+6\end{array}}&\\\phantom{\color{Magenta}{x^{2}}+1}&\begin{array}{rrrr}-\phantom{2 x^{3}}&\phantom{+3 x^{2}}&\phantom{+5 x}&\phantom{+6}\\\phantom{\enclose{longdiv}{}}2 x^{3}&+0 x^{2}&+2 x\\\hline\phantom{\enclose{longdiv}{}}&\color{GoldenRod}{3 x^{2}}&+3 x&+6\\&-\phantom{3 x^{2}}&\phantom{+3 x}&\phantom{+6}\\\phantom{\enclose{longdiv}{}}&3 x^{2}&+0 x&+3\\\hline\phantom{\enclose{longdiv}{}}&&\color{Green}{3 x}&\color{Green}{+3}\end{array}&\begin{array}{c}\phantom{2 x^{3}+3 x^{2}+5 x+6}\\\phantom{\color{Crimson}{2 x}\left(\color{Magenta}{x^{2}}+1\right)=2 x^{3}+2 x}\\\frac{\color{GoldenRod}{3 x^{2}}}{\color{Magenta}{x^{2}}}=\color{GoldenRod}{3}\\\phantom{3 x^{2}+3 x+6}\\\color{GoldenRod}{3}\left(\color{Magenta}{x^{2}}+1\right)=3 x^{2}+3\\\phantom{3 x+3}\end{array}\end{array}$$

so $2x^3+3x^2+5x+6=(2x+3)(x^2+1) +3x+3$ but here $(2x+3)(x^2+1) \in \langle x^2+1\rangle$ so I have that $$2x^3+3x^2+5x+6+ \langle x^2+1\rangle =(2x+3)(x^2+1) +3x+3 + \langle x^2+1\rangle \underset{?}{=} 3x+3 + \langle x^2+1\rangle.$$

What is the deal with the remainder here? The way I've understood the ring $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is that we're killing $x^2+1$ and in the process a bunch of other elements of $\Bbb Z[x]$ also.

Comment: Hello :) You're correct, for all $p\in \mathbb Z[x]$ there is a representitive $q\in \mathbb Z[x]$ with $\deg(q)<2$, such that $p-q\in \langle x^2+1\rangle $ (which is the same as $\overline p=\overline q\in\mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$).

Comment: Building on the comment of @Jochen, the observation that you are making is the version of Euclid's division lemma which holds in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.